# How to combine standard errors from multiple regressions over age

Tags: regression, standard-error

I have a dataset with the number of events (numerator) and population (denominator) by age and year. My aim is to calculate a growth rate for each age over the years with how much uncertainty there is. To do this, I'm running a WLS of the log of the rate [ln(numerator/denominator)] with year as an independent variable, for each age separately.

The issue I have is that the standard error on the year coefficient on each individual is much larger than if I run a regression over the sum of all ages, because there are smaller numbers and more variability (individual age average: +/-1.3%; all ages:0.3%).

So my question is, can anyone advise on the most appropriate way to combine the standard errors from the individual age regressions please?

Comment: Why not run one analysis using all the data?

Comment: @mdewey can you explain what you mean please?

Comment: Fit a model to all the data with age as a fixed effect and probably also with an age by year interaction if that fits your scientific question.